# SQL запрос не ищет, если поле NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Такая проблема, у меня поисковый запрос состоит из нескольких полей

```
if( isset($_POST['submit_search']) )
    {
        
        $Number = $_POST['Number'];
        $Name = $_POST['Name'];
        $Format = $_POST['Format'];
        $Orig_num = $_POST['Orig_num'];
        $Orig_Date = $_POST['Orig_Date'];
        $Dup_num = $_POST['Dup_num'];
        $Dup_Date = $_POST['Dup_Date'];
        
        echo $Dup_num;
        //Номера документов из главной таблицы(ineum_archive_fileindex_main),последние три цифры
        $sql= "select DocumentNumber 
                from in_main 
                WHERE SelectionDescription = '$SelectionDescription' 
                AND Sheet = '1' 
                AND DocumentNumber LIKE '%$Number%' 
                AND DocumentName LIKE '%$Name%'
                AND DocumnetFormat LIKE '%$Format%'
                AND OriginalInventoryNumber LIKE '%$Orig_num%'
                AND OriginalDataSupplay LIKE '%$Orig_Date%'
                AND DuplicationInventoryNumber LIKE '%$Dup_num%'
                AND DuplicationDataSupplay LIKE '%$Dup_Date%'
                order by id desc";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }
```

---

Если в базе данных все поля заполнены и нет пустых(NULL), то поиск выполняется корректно.
Но если я выполняю поиск не по всем полям , а например только по $Number, остальные ячейки ввода для поиска оставляю пустые ($Name, $Format и т.д.). А в базе какие-то из этих ячеек тоже пустые (NULL), то ничего не найдет.

---

Пример1: Number=1, Name=Tom, Format=D, Orig_num=1, Orig_date=2019, Dup_naum=2, Dup_Date=2020. Если в базе есть такие данные, то все найдет корректно.

---

Пример2: Number=1. То есть поиск только по number, а остальным полям не задаем фильтр. Если в базе хотя бы одно из остальных полей, которые используются в запросе SQL будет NULL, то ничего не найдет, хотя должно.

Comment: Задайте вопрос иначе: почему вы решили что наблюдаемое поведение неверное. Потому что так и должно быть. Сравнение чего угодно с NULL - это NULL. В SQL троичная логика.

Comment: @Мелкий а как это избежать?Или обыграть, чтобы работало корректно

Comment: Для начала найти адекватный учебный материал. Критерий - там не конкатенируют данные пользователя с текстом запроса, а используют api prepared stmt. Затем строите текст запроса динамически и добавляете в него только те фильтры, которые использовал пользователь.

Comment: Вот [готовый пример](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/search_filter) того, о чем говорит Мелкий - в запрос добавляются только не пустые поля, и используются подготовленные выражения.

Comment: @Мелкий спасибо

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо, правильно ли я понял, что смысл данного кода в том, чтобы проверять все переменные на содержание там чего-либо?

Comment: @Ипатьев это только первая подобная задача, с которыми мне предстоит столкнуться. А есть ли полезные сайты или материалы, где подобные задачи уже разобраны, чтобы не изобретать велосипед?

Comment: ну в общем да. В принципе, если тип сравнения везде одинаковый, то можно засунуть в цикл. Но вообще я не очень понимаю дату, которая ищется с лайком, а не простым сравнением.

Comment: ну вот этот сайт и есть, там куча примеров для базовых операций

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо, ну например, когда нужно найти не точную дату, а только год

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение с `NULL` всегда даст `FALSE`, даже так: `NULL=NULL`.
Если хотите чтобы в выборке участвовали поля с `NULL`, то добавте в условие выборки:

```
col1 IS NULL AND col2=1 AND col3!='deleted'
```